# Память в C++, разные значения поля в связном списке

Tags: c++

В связном списке создаются объекты с одинаковым адресом памяти и разными значениями их полей.Как такое возможно? Знающих прошу не минусовать, а ответить.Буду очень благодарен.

```
class LinkList
{
    struct Node
    {
        int a;
        Node* next;
    };

    Node* head=nullptr;

public:
    void add(int x)
    {
        Node* current = new Node;
        current->a = x;
        current->next = head;
        head = current;
    }
    void print()
    {
        while (head != NULL)
        {
            cout << head->a <<"  location: "<<&head<<endl;
            head = head->next;
        }
    }
};

int main(){
     LinkList obj;

        obj.add(1);
        obj.add(2);
        obj.add(3);
        obj.add(4);
        obj.add(5);

     obj.print();


    return 0;
}
```

вывод:

```
5  location: 0x22fecc
4  location: 0x22fecc
3  location: 0x22fecc
2  location: 0x22fecc
1  location: 0x22fecc
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В `print()` вы печатаете *адрес указателя `head`*. Заметьте: не адрес, хранящийся в `head`, а адрес самого `head`.

Решение - убрать `&` отсюда:

```
cout << head->a <<"  location: "<<&head<<endl;
```

---

Еще: ваш `print()` делает странные вещи: он очищает список, и заставляет утечь все ноды.

Вместо того, чтобы модифицировать `head`, стоит сделать его копию и работать с копией.

---

Еще: очень советую прочитать и осмыслить [RAII](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) и [правило трех](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_(C%2B%2B)). Связные списки и другие структуры данных - это, конечно, хорошо. Но если из них течет память, как из решета, и они вызывают краши при совершенно невинных манипуляциях, толку от них немного.